# Python Pandas Pivot Table - Adding calculated column to multi-index column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table, which is a multi-index, for both the indices and the columns:

```
Category        HF                      DA      
                tafp    tap     tw      tafp    tap     tafp
ATTR    EL                      
attr1   1.0     10      25      15      100     150     50
attr2   2.0     0       0       0       40      70      30
        3.0     20      50      30      0       0       0
attr3   2.0     0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Here's a dict of this pivot table (values are a bit different, but that doesn't matter):

```
{
('HF', 'tafp'): {('attr1', '1.0'): 10, ('attr2', '2.0'): 100, ('attr3','2.0'): 0, ('attr4', '2.0'): 0, ('attr2', '3.0'): 71},
('HF', 'tap'): {('attr1', '1.0'): 30, ('attr2', '2.0'): 350, ('attr3', '2.0'): 0, ('attr4', '2.0'): 0, ('attr2', '3.0'): 1042},
('HF', 'tw'): {('attr1', '1.0'): 20, ('attr2', '2.0'): 250, ('attr3', '2.0'): 0, ('attr4', '2.0'): 0, ('attr2', '3.0'): 971},
('DA', 'tafp'): {('attr1', '1.0'): 0, ('attr2', '2.0'): 435, ('attr3', '2.0'): 0, ('attr4', '2.0'): 0, ('attr2', '3.0'): 0},
('DA', 'tap'): {('attr1', '1.0'): 0, ('attr2', '2.0'): 635, ('attr3', '2.0'): 0, ('attr4', '2.0'): 0, ('attr2', '3.0'): 0},
('DA', 'tw'): {('attr1', '1.0'): 0, ('attr2', '2.0'): 200, ('attr3', '2.0'): 0, ('attr4', '2.0'): 0, ('attr2', '3.0'): 0}
}
```

What I want to get in the end, is the following:

```
Category        HF                      DA      
                tafp/tap    tw      tafp/tap    tafp
ATTR    EL                      
attr1   1.0     0.67        15      0.67        50
attr2   2.0     0           0       0.57        30
        3.0     0.67        30      0           0
attr3   2.0     0           0       0           0
```

So I would like to get the percentage of tafp/tap and only keep this calculated column, i.e. delete the original columns.

Does somebody have an idea how I can achieve this?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some steps.

First stack level 0  `('DA,HF')` letting level 1 `('tafp','tap')` as columns for easier handling.

```
df=df.stack(level=0)
"""
              tafp   tap   tw
attr1 1.0 DA     0     0    0
          HF    10    30   20
attr2 2.0 DA   435   635  200
          HF   100   350  250
      3.0 DA     0     0    0
          HF    71  1042  971
attr3 2.0 DA     0     0    0
          HF     0     0    0
attr4 2.0 DA     0     0    0
          HF     0     0    0
"""
```

Then the operation:

```
valid=df.tap>0
df.tafp[valid] /= df.tap[valid]
```

Finally the reformatting :

```
df=df.drop('tap',axis=1).unstack()
df.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

for :

```
"""
                 DA             HF     
               tafp   tw      tafp   tw
attr1 1.0  0.000000    0  0.333333   20
attr2 2.0  0.685039  200  0.285714  250
      3.0  0.000000    0  0.068138  971
attr3 2.0  0.000000    0  0.000000    0
attr4 2.0  0.000000    0  0.000000    0
"""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm. Could you clarify the use of the 'level' argument in stack and unstack? I do understand what it means, but e.g why do you use level=2 when unstacking?

Comment: because ('HF','DA') is now the third (index 2) column of  rows index, but it is the default,so I remove it.